# Compilation error while building Apache 2.4.10 on windows

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

I am getting following error while building Apache 2.4.10 on windows.

```
       cd ..
        nmake -nologo -f libhttpd.mak        CFG="libhttpd - Win32 Release" RECURSE=0
        if not exist ".\Release/" mkdir ".\Release"
        tempfile.bat
        tempfile.bat
        cl.exe /nologo /MD /W3 /Zi /O2 /Oy- /I "./include" /I "./srclib/apr/include" /I "./srclib/ap
r-util/include" /I "./srclib/pcre" /D "NDEBUG" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "PCRE_STATIC" /D "AP_DECL
ARE_EXPORT" /Fo".\Release\\" /Fd".\Release\libhttpd_cl" /FD /c .\modules\http\byterange_filter.c
byterange_filter.c
modules\http\byterange_filter.c(512) : error C2065: 'ap_multipart_boundary' : undeclared identifier
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I check the http_core.c file in the same directory and it has this entry

```
AP_DECLARE_DATA const char *ap_multipart_boundary;
```

but http_core.h file in the include directory doesn't have this entry. There is no other error or warning is seen before this error.

I don't have much experience in C and new to Apache building. Can you please tell what I might be missing?

I am using Windows Server 2003 SP2 and "Microsoft Visual C++ 2003". The same environment I am able to build Apache 2.2.22 without any issue.

Comment: "Windows" is not enough info to guess which version of Visual Studio you are using. Since newer versions of the Windows compiler toolchain implement new features in the C/C++ standard library and compiler, it may be necessary to use a newer version than whatever you're using.

Comment: Also consider using MinGW64 to build it instead of the Visual Studio toolchain. It produces binary-compatible code that can link against code built with Visual Studio, but it's based on `gcc`. It tends to fare better with building FOSS projects than Visual Studio.

Comment: I have given environment details. I would prefer using Visual Studio as we are using it from long time and it had worked fine.

Comment: Doesn't matter if 2.2.22 worked fine -- it's perfectly understandable for the Apache project to add code in the new 2.4 release that makes it not build with an 11 year-old toolchain. Upgrade to Visual Studio C++ 2008 or 2010 or 2012 or 2013 and try again.